# Libgdx Getting error when removing Sprite

Tags: java, exception, libgdx, collision, rectangles

I'm trying to remove my enemy sprite whenever they collide to a rectangle,I'm also using Pools.

```
while(enemyIterator.hasNext()){
            Sprite sprite=enemyIterator.next();  //this is the line 65
            if(enemyRect.overlaps(treeObj.treeRect))
                removeEnemy(sprite);
        }
```

then on remove enemy method:

```
public void removeEnemy(Sprite sprite){
        enemies.remove(sprite);
        Pools.free(sprite);
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
        at com.dreamroad.savethetree.EnemyClass.update(EnemyClass.java:65)
        at com.dreamroad.savethetree.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:51)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

I followed the instruction from the question he linked and I still get the error, for now I'm only trying to remove the rectangles.

```
for(Iterator<Rectangle> rectIterator=rectangles.iterator();rectIterator.hasNext();){
            Rectangle nextRect=rectIterator.next();
            if(nextRect.overlaps(treeObj.treeRect))
                rectIterator.remove();
        }
```

Comment: I still get the same error, why don't you just answer my question since you know a lot!

Comment: Your issue is nothing to do with Pools, Sprites etc and everything to do with  concurrent modification. John Skeet is absolutely correct to mark it as a duplicate. I suggest you read and fully digest the question he linked.